# PowerShell output text to a file as a table/columns

Tags: powershell

In a loop, the code will output text to a file, basically two vars, however the width of each var is variable and the output looks ugly.
Is there a way to output the two vars in "columns", as a table?

Current code in the loop (the variables are concatenated in the sample code):

```
$matches[0] + $cal | Add-Content -LiteralPath $cleancalendarslist
```

Comment: Did you think about using Export-CSV?

Comment: Not really, I was looking for a plain text solution

Comment: take a look at the `-f` string format operator. is allows setting field size and left/right alignment.

Comment: CSV _is_ a plain-text solution. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Bill, CSV requires opening the text from Excel or compatible program. Just looking for plain text formatted columns. Will have a look into the -f operator

Comment: The [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) should do what you're asking. However, I'd recommend to reconsider exporting to CSV instead of unstructured text, because a structured format like gives you far more flexibility and you can easily view it with tools like [CSVed](https://csved.sjfrancke.nl/index.html) (which doesn't require installation) or even `Import-Csv 'your.csv' | Out-GridView`.

Comment: Thanks............

Comment: BTW, another (very simplistic) solution might be to just put a tab character between your variables (``$matches[0] + "`t$cal" | Add-Content ...``). That would produce table-ish plain text output, while still allowing you to read the file as a CSV by specifying a tab as the delimiter character (e.g. ``Import-Csv 'your.txt' -Delimiter "`t" -Header 'foo', 'bar' | Out-GridView``).

Comment: Lee, I would vote for your solution

Comment: "CSV requires opening the text from Excel or compatible program." I don't know what you mean by that, but it is not true. Just use `Import-Csv` and you will get output objects in a quite readable format right at the PowerShell prompt. You can even pipe to `Out-GridView` to view the objects in a GUI window for sorting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i agree csv is a plain text solution, and it doesn't require opening with excel - but i think this is what you are looking for:  and it is using PadLeft()

```
$matches = @('short','this is a long string','a med string')
$maxlength = ($matches | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
$cal = '20190107'  #not sure what cal is....

foreach($s in $array){
    $paddedstring = $s.Padleft($maxlength,' ')
    $paddedstring + ' ' + $cal | add-content -LiteralPath $cleancalendarslist
}
```